# Time consumption of SciPy's bootstrap as a function of the number of resamples

Tags: python, scipy, statistics-bootstrap, scipy.stats

I have a large dataset, with on the order of 2^15 entries, and I calculate the confidence interval of the mean of the entries with [`scipy.stats.bootstrap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html). For a dataset this size, this costs about 6 seconds on my laptop. I have a lot of datasets, so I find this takes too long (especially if I just want to do a test run to debug the plotting etc.). By default, SciPy's bootstrapping function resamples the data `n_resamples=9999` times. As I understand it, the resampling and computing the average of the resampled data should be the most time-consuming part of the process. However, when I reduce the number of resamples by roughly three orders of magnitude (`n_resamples=10`), the computational time of the bootstrapping method does not even half.

I'm using Python 3 and SciPy 1.9.3.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from time import perf_counter

data = np.random.rand(2**15)
data = np.array([data])

start = perf_counter()
bs = stats.bootstrap(data, np.mean, batch=1, n_resamples=9999)
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = perf_counter()
bs = stats.bootstrap(data, np.mean, batch=1, n_resamples=10)
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)

start = perf_counter()
bs = stats.bootstrap(data, np.mean, n_resamples=10)
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)
```

gives

```
6.021066904067993
3.9989020824432373
30.46708607673645
```

To speed up bootstrapping, I have set `batch=1`. As I understand it, this is more memory efficient, and prevents swapping the data. Setting a higher batch number increases the time consumption, as you can see above.

How can I do faster bootstrapping?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I don't remember, but I don't think so. Possibly, I just reduced the size of the datasets for testing and debugging.

Comment: Ok. I ended up with a quick re-implementation of the sampling part of starts.bootstrap using np.random.choice() and improving the statistic function.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Try passing `method='basic'` or `method='percentile`'. Also, pass a NumPy `Generator` for the random state (e.g. `random_state=np.random.default_rng()`).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from time import perf_counter
rng = np.random.default_rng(234893458942534)

data = np.random.rand(2**15)
data = np.array([data])

start = perf_counter()
bs = stats.bootstrap(data, np.mean, batch=1, n_resamples=10)
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)  # 13.304466278000064

start = perf_counter()
bs = stats.bootstrap(data, np.mean, batch=None, n_resamples=10, 
                     method='basic', random_state=rng)
end = perf_counter()
print(end-start)  # 0.0040362729999969815
```

This should free up enough time to do more resamples.

---

The default `method='BCa'`. This is the bias-corrected and accelerated bootstrap, which performs the jackknife to estimate the acceleration parameter. The jackknife evaluates the statistic with *N* jackknife resamples, where *N* is the number of observations in the sample; each is your original sample with one observation removed. This explains why reducing the number of bootstrap resamples does not reduce the execution time much: it's dominated by the jackknife. The other methods don't need to do the jackknife.

Passing the `Generator` for the random state boosts the speed a bit because it's faster at generating the resamples than the old `RandomState` (default).

> Setting a higher batch number increases the time consumption, as you can see above.

When the sample size is large, sure, but not in general. For smaller samples with a vectorized statistic function like `np.mean`, leaving `batch=None` or using a moderate value (e.g. `batch=100`) tends to be much faster than `batch=1` because less Python looping is required.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for sample sizes > 20k. First memory problems, and with batch_size=1 for 25k it did not even return.

I needed up rewriting the re-sampling part of bootstrap() and copying some code out of it:

```
def bootstrap_test_fast(y_true, y_pred, statistic=cal_recall, n_resamples=1000):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    confidence_level=0.95
    alternative='two-sided'  
    data = np.stack((y_true, y_pred))

    ndata = len(y_true)
    theta_hat_b = []
    for n in range(1000):
        resampled = rng.choice(a=data, size=ndata, replace=True, axis=1)
        theta_hat_b.append(statistic(resampled[0], resampled[1]))


    alpha = ((1 - confidence_level) / 2 if alternative == 'two-sided' else (1 - confidence_level))
    interval = alpha, 1 - alpha

    def percentile_fun(a, q):
        return np.percentile(a=a, q=q, axis=-1)

    ci_l = percentile_fun(theta_hat_b, interval[0] * 100)
    ci_u = percentile_fun(theta_hat_b, interval[1] * 100)
    theta_hat = statistic(np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred))
    ci_l, ci_u = 2 * theta_hat - ci_u, 2 * theta_hat - ci_l

    return stats._resampling.BootstrapResult( confidence_interval = stats._resampling.ConfidenceInterval(ci_l, ci_u),
                       bootstrap_distribution=theta_hat_b,
                       standard_error=np.std(theta_hat_b, ddof=1, axis=-1))
```

Code is much faster. Sampling 200k samples with N=1000 takes about 15 seconds.